# Unmarshal not valid JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel

I'm trying to unmarshal JSON resource with Camel.
I do like this

```
from("timer:trigger").to("http://example.com/json")
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson);
```

The problem is that data seems a bit broken and JSON starts from

```
)]}',
```

of course I get exception like

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: 
Unexpected character (')' (code 41)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
```

how could I skip this characters or just ignore part of JSON?

Comment: Why is the JSON invalid?

Comment: Because it starts from )]}', and after coma I have actual data

Comment: Yes, but my question was why it had that invalid data in it? Is the source messing something up? Is it always the same invalid data or will the source start sending some other invalid data some day? etc. Anyhow, Matt's answer addresses it.

Comment: It's third-party API. As for now I see that it's actually possible to trim 5 chars from start of the string. I have no idea what could happen in future.

Comment: If that part always appear, just remove that part in a preprocessing step and then do your json parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If it is known to be bad json, your best bet is to pre-process the data with a java bean or template of some sort, then pass it to jackson. It is a lot to ask the library to know how to "get exactly what I want" out of a stream of malformed data.